# google anaylitics visitor counter fail to return using API

Tags: google-analytics-api, asp.net-4.0

I have written following code in a handler to get visitor counter in asp.net website

```
using Google.Analytics;
using Google.GData.Analytics; //v2.2.0.0

public class Visitor : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    AccountQuery feedQuery = new AccountQuery();
    AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("kiranaAnalytic");

    service.setUserCredentials("myemailid@gmail.com", "mypassword");

    DataQuery pageViewQuery = new DataQuery("https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data");//https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data
    pageViewQuery.Ids = "ga:xxxx";
    pageViewQuery.Metrics = "ga:visitors";
    pageViewQuery.GAStartDate = "2014-05-01";//DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    pageViewQuery.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DataEntry pvEntry = service.Query(pageViewQuery).Entries[0] as DataEntry;

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(pvEntry.Metrics[0].Value);
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

It was working fine till yeaterday. But I am suddenly started getting following error.
"Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of authentication request returned"

Has anyone have idea about it or did google made some changes ?

Comment: similar issue has been reported at google [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5101)

Comment: did you get solution using **OAuth** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Yes. I have followed the DaImTo suggestions. http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/

Comment: @Kiquenet One more thing, you have to add permission for serviceAccountEmail (eg xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com) in  google anyalitc

Answer (score 1):

This means there is something wrong with your authentication. You appear to be using Login and password which is called client login.

Client login which was discontinued / shutdown on [April 20 2015](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable) and I suspect turned off on Tuesday for Google Analytics.  You can no longer use client login with Google Analytics API, you need to switch to Oauth2 or a service account.   I recommend using the  [Google .net client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/).

**tutorial**:  [Google Analytics API C# Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Google shutdown the old account-password authentication. You need to move your code to use Oauth.